# RegEx for matching all email ID's

Tags: regex

I have wrote the regex to match the email ID's in the event but however, the regex is not matching all the email ID's in a single event before '@.  It is only matching the first email until before "@" but not the second email until before "@'

Sample Events :

```
(14.2) 04-01-18 00:03:38 (1944:3676)  PRINTFN: $G_NOTIFY_GRP_INTERNAL: peter.parker@abc.com,thomas.holland03@abc.com 
(14.2) 04-01-18 04:14:38 (5796:5968)  PRINTFN: $G_NOTIFY_GRP_INTERNAL:  henry.pete@abc.com,grant.subarao@abc.com
```

REGEX that i wrote:

```
(?m)^(.*?)([A-z0-9._%+-]+\@)(.*)$
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @Wiktor: OP doesn't want to match or extract the email from his text. He wants to match only the username part from all the emails. Please reopen this post.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Just move the closing parenthesis to just before the `@` in the duplicate post’s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `^` start and `$` end anchors if you want your regex to match all the email addresses, and also your email needs some corrections to match it with an email. Try using this regex to match your emails,

```
[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[^,\s]*
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eg0cPu/1)**

Although, this regex for matching email is just enough after modifying yours to remove the errors but just to make your emails match and a more robust email would also ensure further validity of email by checking more patterns like presence of `.` after @ etc.

**Edit:**
As per your comments to my post,

> Thank you for the reply. However, the provided regex is matching the
>   entire email ID but however, i am trying to match the email ID before
>   the "@"

You need to use a positive look ahead for only matching the part before `@` using this regex,

```
[A-z0-9._%+-]+(?=@[^,\s]*)
```

**[Regex Demo matching email before `@` part](https://regex101.com/r/eg0cPu/2)**

Also, here is why your regex `(?m)^(.*?)([A-z0-9._%+-]+\@)(.*)$` didn't work the way you wanted.

If you want multiple matches in your text, you can't use `^` start or `$` end anchor when the number of expected possible matches is not definite and may vary depending upon the data. So firstly you need to get rid of `^` and `$` from your regex and hence, next `(?m)` multiline mode also becomes useless as now there is no `^` or `$`. Now you're left with `(.*?)([A-z0-9._%+-]+\@)(.*)` regex. Now the problem with this regex is, (.*?) will match text before your first email's username part so that `([A-z0-9._%+-]+\@)` matches your first email's username part and then `(.*)` match any remaining characters hence your second email gets consumed in matching `.*` which is why you don't see second email's username part matching. For getting proper matches, you need to use my regex.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, the provided regex is matching the entire email ID but however, i am trying to match the email ID before the "@".

Comment: @learningfun: Sure, that can be done easily. Just wait few seconds.

Comment: @learningfun: Updated my answer with what you were looking. Please check. I will also update why your regex didn't work the way you expected.

Comment: @learningfun: I've also updated why your post didn't work. Let me know if you have any queries or confusion further.